# Is there a way to say "region-locked" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

I feel like there should be a way to say it when talking about things not being available in certain regions.

Comment: Do you mean region codes of DVDs, say, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the region-based restriction system of DVD/Blu-ray or online platforms like Steam? If yes, *region-lock* (system) is simply リージョンロック in Japanese. *Region-locked DVD* is リージョンロックがかかったDVD or リージョンロックのかかったDVD. Alternatively, リージョン固定のDVD and リージョンコード付きのDVD essentially refer to the same thing. *Region-free* is simply リージョンフリー(の).

Comment: How about online video content stating "content is not available in your geographic location" (a common occurrence as I am not in Japan)?